# SVN online backup solution

Tags: svn, cloud, backup, restore

We use SVN which is installed on a local server and we are looking for an online backup solution.
Our upload bandwidth is quite poor so the two following are not an option:

- use a cloud SVN server as our main SVN server
- upload big amounts of data

Does anyone have a successfully tested solution to offer?

It seems to me that a cloud-based sync backup solution would be good. However, I need to know how this would work with SVN. In particular, how would restoration work?
Does anyone have experience with this?
Alternatively, does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: Feels like a better question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/svn).